# How do I evaluate this indefinite integral?

Tags: integration, analysis, indefinite-integrals

I am currently working on the following problem:

> $\int x  (2x+3)^{99}$

I have tried using u-substitution $(u = 2x+3)$ and integration by parts, but have not been able to make any progress that leads me to an answer. I thought about actually computing $(2x+3)^{99}$, but I think that would make the problem even more complicated. How would I go about solving this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but just split the result into $2$ integrations after you make the substitution. In particular,

$$u = 2x + 3 \Rightarrow du = 2dx \Rightarrow dx = \frac{du}{2} \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

Also,

$$x = \frac{u - 3}{2} \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

Thus,

$$\int x\left(2x + 3\right)^{99}dx = \int \frac{u - 3}{4}u^{99} du = \frac{1}{4}\int u^{100} du - \frac{3}{4}\int u^{99} du \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

I assume you should be able to finish the rest.

Comment: Yes, John. At this point I can finish up the problem. I knew I needed to split the integral somehow, but did not know how to do it.

Comment: @JohnSmith I'm glad you see how to do it now.

Answer (score 2):

Integration by parts works: 
$$\int x(2x+3)^{99}dx=x\cdot\frac{(2x+3)^{100}}{2\cdot100}-\int\frac{(2x+3)^{100}}{2\cdot100}dx$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: I will try out integration by parts once I've finished solving it using u-substitution, Michael. Other than that, I can take it from here.

Comment: OK. Good luck, @John!

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\int x(2x+3)^{99} dx=\int\frac{u-3}{4}u^{99}du=\frac{1}{4}\int (u^{100}-3u^{99})du=\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{u^{101}}{101}-\frac{3u^{100}}{100}\right)+C.$$

Comment: Much appreciated, J.G. I believe I have enough to take it from here.